# SplashScreen not closing in javaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I am using JavaFX to create an application. SplashScreen opens properly and sets on the screen even after the application opens.

Here are my codes:

#### Main Class:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class SplashScreen extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent  root=FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("SplashScreenFXML.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

#### Controller Class:

```
package splashscreen;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class SplashScreenFXMLController implements Initializable 
{

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane rootPane;

        @Override
      public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) 
   {
       new SplashScreen().start();
    }
      class SplashScreen extends Thread
     {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        try {
                            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("FXMLDocument.fxml"));

                            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
                            Stage stage=new Stage();
                            stage.setScene(scene);
                            stage.show();  
                            rootPane.getScene().getWindow().hide();


                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                          Logger.getLogger(SplashScreenFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                    }
                });


            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                     Logger.getLogger(SplashScreenFXMLController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

can Anybody help me with this?
I think `rootPane.getScene().getWindow().hide();` this is not working. Is there any otherway that I can hide the `SplashScreen` Stage?

Comment: Any exceptions? Or does it just simply refused to hide? Does the new window open?

Comment: New window is opening but the old window is not hidden. I am not getting any exceptions.

Comment: You will need to step through your codes and see if it actually reaches that line.

Comment: Ok thank you.. I'll check..

Comment: I got an exception in thread while step through -"JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Which line threw the exception?

Comment: rootPane.getScene().getWindow().hide();  in the controller code

Comment: `FXMLLoader.load` created and init `SplashScreenFXMLController` before your create scene. Why not use javafx `Preloader` ?

Comment: https://github.com/sedj601/SplashScreenTest

Comment: Thank you. But I would like to use FXML also. so how can i do that ?

Comment: Thank you @mrmcwolf  It is resolved with Preloader.